# How to check dispatch_async queue status?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In a typical `dispatch_async` execution:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    // ...
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // ...
    });
});
```

To limit only there is only a block running:

```
if (_loadingFromServer) return;
_loadingFromServer = YES;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    // ...
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // ...
        _loadingFromServer = NO;
    });
});
```

Is there a way to check where the async block is running, *without* using a `_loadingFromServer` flag?

Is `dispatch_queue_set_specific` helpful in this case?

Answer (score -1):

use Serial Dispatch Queues to execute one task at a time

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html

Like this

```
 dispatch_queue_t myQueue;
 myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("myQueue", NULL);
 dispatch_async(myQueue, block);
```